# Can I reuse grounds to make another espresso?

Tags: espresso

I have [this espresso/latte machine](https://chefman.com/products/espresso-machine). How many times can I make a cup from the same espresso grounds?

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is **one extraction per portafilter filling.**
So depending on whether you use the smaller one-shot or larger double-shot insert, you get one or two shots per button press *and after that, the grounds are considered spent*.

If you’d try to leave the grounds and push the button again and again, you wouldn’t just get increasingly weaker brews, but you would notice a lot of unpleasant flavors, from excessive bitterness to sour notes. It may seem wasteful, but that’s how espresso works - you pretty much get the best of each load in one go and that’s it.

———-

Anecdotally, I know of a somewhat strange habit in a few Swiss households that will keep once-used Nespresso capsules (which can count as “a serving of espresso grounds”) and will use it once again for a purposely weak brew that goes into making „Kafi Fertig“ („finished coffee“), a concoction that gets spiked with a generous amount of „Träsch“ (a fruit brandy) and sugar. But that’s not a practical option for a spent coffee puck which can and probably will fall apart, not to mention the food safety issues if you tried to keep it for a while. I very much don’t recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

> How many times can I make a cup from the same espresso grounds?

## Once

All of the components that make coffee the way it tastes will be extracted during the first extraction. If not, then something went wrong - perhaps too low of a brew temperature, too coarse a grind or even too fast of a brew time. Additionally, the caffeine inside the coffee will mostly be in your beverage as caffeine dissolves very readily in water. Finally, there might be associated health risks - warm, moist, finely ground organic matter is the perfect breeding ground for mold.